# Verb after ～にこたえて

Tags: grammar, usage

I encountered the following multiple-choice question on page 37 (question 3 in section 5) of my JLPT N2 grammar textbook 「新完全マスター文法　日本語能力試験Ｎ２」:

> 歴史的な大記録を作った斎藤選手は、祝福の拍手にこたえて（　　　）。
>
> ａ 帽子を取って軽くおじぎをした
>
> ｂ 大きな声で返事をした
>
> ｃ とても満足した様子だった

The answer is 「ａ 帽子を取って軽くおじぎをした」.  I chose the correct option and understand why it is correct, but I am not sure why the option 「ｂ 大きな声で返事をした」 is wrong.  My textbook explains ～にこたえて as

> #### ～にこたえて
>
> ～の期待・要望がかなうように、あることをする。
>
> 「期待・要望・希望・アンコール」など限られた言葉につく。後には、動詞の文が来る。

「ｃ とても満足した様子だった」 is not 動詞の文, so I eliminated it.  However, options 「ａ 帽子を取って軽くおじぎをした」 and 「ｂ 大きな声で返事をした」 both seem to make sense to me:

> (a) 歴史的な大記録を作った斎藤選手は、祝福の拍手にこたえて帽子を取って軽くおじぎをした。
>
> Saitō, who set a historical great record, took off their hat and bowed gentally in response to congratulatory applause.

> (b) （？）歴史的な大記録を作った斎藤選手は、祝福の拍手にこたえて大きな声で返事をした。
>
> Saitō, who set a historical great record, responded loudly to congratulatory applause.

I chose (a) only because the scenario described was more imaginable to me, but I cannot find anything wrong with (b).  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

祝福の拍手にこたえて大きな声で返事をした is OK except こたえて and 返事をした make it redundant. It’s like saying the player responded with a loud voice in response to the applause of congratulations. It would sound more natural to say 祝福の拍手に大きな声で返事をした.